# Do not zip files that have already been zipped

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bunch of files in a directory that I want zipped:

```
for i in $dir/*; do
  if [[ ! "$i" =~ "zip" ]]; then
    zip $i
  else
    echo "$i has already been zipped"
  fi
done
```

If I populate the directory with a new files and run the script again, it will re-zip all files that don't contain the string "zip". How do I skip those files that are unzipped but already have a zip file in the same directory?

For example, the script should not zip `testing.log` again because it already has a zip version in the same directory:

```
testing.log testing.log.zip
```

**UPDATE - 03/15/2018**

Thanks for all your feedback! The script now looks like:

```
for i in $dir/*.log; do
  if [[ ! -f "${i}.zip" ]]; then
    zip $i
  else
    echo "$i has already been zipped"
  fi
done
```

Comment: `[ -f "${i}.zip" ]` ?

Comment: I should have done this `for i in $dir/*.log` instead of `for i in $dir/*`

Comment: @Francis, it should be `[ ! -f "${i}.zip" ]; then zip "${i}.zip" "$i"`

Comment: if `[ -f "${i}.zip" -o "$i" = "${i%.zip}" ]` then skip

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in $dir/*; do
  if [ -f "${i}.zip" -o "${i}" = "${i%.zip}" ]; then
    echo "${i} has already been zipped"
    continue
  fi
  zip $i
done
```

Where `[ -f "${i}.zip" ]` checks the existence of the corresponding zip file and `[ "${i}" = "${i%.zip}" ]` checks whether the file itself is a zip file.

Answer (score 2):

You can even use a character class to help with initial file selection by excluding files with `zip` in their extension. For example

```
for i in "$dir"/*.[^z]*; do    ## exclude all files w/ext beginning with 'z'
    zip "$i"
done
```

Just another approach to take that comes at the issue from another angle.

Comment: How does this skip files of which an accompanying .zip version already exists ?

Comment: It skips by using the inverted character class `.[^z]` as the first letter of the extension. Meaning it only matches files that do NOT have an extension that begins with `'z'`.  (`zip` and `zoo` files are about the only I can think of that normally begin with `'z'`). So as long as you don't want to attempt to compress an already compressed `.zoo` file -- this just skip both `.zip` and `.zoo` and `.zwhatever`

Comment: Keep in  mind that the source file remains in the directory. So after compressing `foo.txt`, both `foo.txt` and `foo.txt.zip` will be in the directory, of which your loop does not prevent recompressing `foo.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

You better manage a history file. For example if you are zipping mylog.log file put that file in a history file like below

```
  echo "$i" >> history.txt
  zip $i
```

and next time while you start the same script it should check whether that file is already available in that `history.txt` file or not. If available in history file do not zip it. So your final script will be look like below:-

```
 if grep "$i" history.txt ; then
    echo "$i already zipped
 else
     echo "$i" >> history.txt
     zip $i
 fi
```

At the very beginning create a history file manually else `if` condition will give you an error message.

Hope this will help

Comment: Then don't forget to skip the `history.txt` file

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like

```
for i in $dir/*; do
    if [ -z ${i##*.zip} ]; then
        # $i ends with ".zip"
        echo "already a zip file: $i"
    elif [ -f ${i}.zip ] ; then
        # there  already exists a zipped file named $i.zip
        echo "already has zipped sibling: $i"
    else
        # actually zip $i into $i.zip
        zip $i.zip $i
    fi
done
```